# log messages to file

Tags: ros, c++, ros-hydro, c++11, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody.
I am trying to write a package for storing some information in a file in order to plot them later (usually in matlab).
I need it in order to check if the things will work properly. Follows a more detailed description of the problem.
What I would like to do is  a simple logger class that would be initialized using the full path to the desired "log" file.
A part from standard constructor and destructor i would like to have a function, lets say something like

```
void logMsg(<generic_msg> m);
```

That takes any ros msg as parameter and writes it to a file in matlab friendly format.
Now I can think of multiple ways of doing it for example:

1. Use overloading. I will define multiple versions of *logMsg* with different parameters and code. Example:

   ```
   void logMsg(nav_msg::Odometry o);
   void logMsg(geometry_msg::Point p);
   ```

   PROS: **easy** to implement
   CONS: **huge** file, code **repetition**, **poor flexibility**
2. Taking a string as input. I will handle the messages as a string and print them to file as a string. However this requires the user to convert the string himself/herself, and this is not what I have in mind. Providing a function that formats the message in a string would end up in the problems above. Example:

   ```
   void logMsg(std::string s);
   ```

std::string toString(<various_types_of_msgs>);

3. ????

I cannot think anything proper for the purpose, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you very much
Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193529/log-messages-to-file/) by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2014-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-26**:
First method looks good, 2nd method output is similar to rostopic echo to text file.

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2014-09-26**:
I  know, but the first method requires implementing each function for each file. I am trying to understand if there is a better way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 3 . ????

.. use [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag) and a suitable bag->X conversion.

From a quick search:

- ROS Answers: [How can I use bag file data in Matlab?](http://answers.ros.org/question/11330/how-can-i-use-bag-file-data-in-matlab/)
- ROS Answers: [How to extract data from *.bag?](http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/) (ROS Answers question)
- Random blog post: [ROS Bag Files](http://cse.unl.edu/%7Ecarrick/wordpress/?p=36)
- [ros-users](http://www.ros.org/news/2013/02/new-package-matlab-rosbag.html) post: [bcharrow/matlab_rosbag](https://github.com/bcharrow/matlab_rosbag): A small library for reading ROS bags in Matlab

etc

---

Edit: Another option might be to use the [official ROS support](http://www.mathworks.nl/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html) released by Mathworks.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2014-09-26**:
Yes right, that was the third option... do you suggest that one?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-26**:
Of course. Why create something yourself, that has been done a 1000 times already? I've also added a 4th option.

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2014-09-26**:
Thank you very much! I will use a rosbag